# Shortest way to reverse a number

Tags: code-golf, number

Write a function (or equivalent subprogram) to accept a single integer valued argument and return a (similarly typed) value found by reversing the order of the base-10 digits of the argument.

For example given 76543 return 34567

Comment: Go back to the time the number was a string, then reverse the string

Comment: The idea of a "shortest algorithm" is somewhat specious, especially if you'll allow "any language." Think up an algorithm, and I'll give you a DSL with an appropriate "~" operator ...

Comment: Just a notice: any number ending with 0 becomes a shorter number of digits when reversed...

Comment: I know an algorithm that takes *no time at all*, but only works on palindromic numbers ;)

Comment: Found time to do the re-write myself. I hope this remain the puzzle that eltond meant to pose.

Comment: The algorithm for palindromic numbers needs at least one time step to output the number ;)

Answer (score 86):

## HTML <strike>21</strike> 7 chars (1 char if I'm cheeky...)

```
&#8238;n
```

replace `n` with your number

Comment: This is just plain genius. I'd go for one char. Or 2, as it encodes to two bytes in UTF-16 :P

Comment: Hahaha I did a Google search on that tag and was rewarded with `Your search -‮ `- did not match any documents.

Comment: U could try this link in browser: `data:text/html,&%238238;egnahcxEkcatS olleH`

Comment: Funny in [google transate](https://translate.google.ch/?tab=wT#en/de/%26%238238%3B%20Test%20this%20string) too. @JoeFish: I can't reproduce, please post a link! ‮

Comment: @JoeFish When I look at the comment, your username is flipped and there is some text after it. ‮txet emos si ereH

Answer (score 33):

Python

`int(str(76543)[::-1])`

**EDIT:**

Shorter solution as suggested by  @gnibbler:

```
int(`76543`[::-1])
```

or, if above is unclear:

```
x=76543
int(`x`[::-1])
```

Comment: `s[::-1]` is a lot faster than `''.join(reversed(s))`

Comment: You can use backticks (for repr) instead of using str

Comment: @gnibbler Thanks for suggestion. I've updated my answer.

Comment: TBH, that ain't a function/proceduce/whatever you want to call it, and the specs require it.

Comment: Also, it doesn't even accept a value...

Comment: Work's only in Python 2

Comment: It doesn't work with negative values.

Comment: This doesn't work with numbers that are longs. Example: ```print int(`2**32`[::-1])```

Answer (score 28):

**Universal (language *agnostic/independent*)**

If you want to use **only numbers** (avoid converting the number to string) and **don't** want to use some **specific** library (to be universal for any language):

```
x = 76543 # or whatever is your number
y = 0
while x > 0:
    y *= 10
    y += ( x %10 )
    x /= 10 # int division
```

<sub>This is python, but it could be done in any language, because it's just a math method.</sub>

Comment: If you replace `mod` with `%`, it's valid Python ;)

Comment: You're right, actually :) 10x

Comment: But see below it is not the shortest way.

Comment: Not the shortest, but the most common and universal.

Comment: `y=y*10+x%10`....

Comment: I prefer this to all the string methods, because it's more efficient and elegant, and some APIs may decide that the reverse of e.g. 110 ('011') is 11 octal.

Comment: Why not use the built-in `divmod()` function? You don't even have to import it.

Comment: Because I wanted to make universal solution, that can be written in any language and I didn't want to use any built-in functions.

Comment: Not every language has a modulus operator... so it's not universal. Just an FYI.

Comment: @mbomb007 that's interesting, for example?

Comment: BrainFuck doesn't, though it can be calculated. Any language that doesn't have it can use `a - (n * int(a/n))` instead of `a mod n`. Also, if you look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), the modulus operation is implemented differently in every language. (See the table on the right.)

Answer (score 13):

### Perl 6

```
+$n.flip
```

or:

```
$n.flip
```

for dynamically typed code.

Numbers got string methods due to language design.

Answer (score 10):

## J - 6 characters + variable

```
".|.":y
```

Where y is your value.

Comment: As a function: `|.&.":` "reverse under do" which is pretty much a literal translation of the task.

Answer (score 10):

### APL (3)

```
⍎⌽⍕
```

Usage:

```
⍎⌽⍕12345 => 54321
```

Answer (score 8):

## PHP, 9 chars

```
(int)strrev(123);
```

To do it short where `N` is a constant:

```
strrev(N)
```

Answer (score 8):

## Vim

17 chars

```
:se ri<CR>C<C-R>"
```

Comment: I would say that's 10 chars (keystrokes) if you type the command directly in vim. Btw, I learned something new in vim today, thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

## Befunge (3 characters)

Complete runnable program:

```
N.@
```

Where `N` is your number. Rules say "accept *a single integer* valued argument"; In Befunge you can only enter integers from 0 to 9.

Comment: Those are the only *literals*, but other numbers could certainly be represented. Otherwise, the winning answer would be Brainfuck with the empty program. ;-)

Answer (score 8):

#### Language-independent/mathematics

Inspired by Kiril Kirov's answer above.  I got curious about the mathematical properties of reversing a number, so I decided to investigate a bit.

Turns out if you plot the difference `n - rev(n)` for natural numbers `n` in some base `r`, you get patterns like this (`(n - rev(n)) / (r - 1)`, for `r=10`, wrapped at `r` columns, red denotes negative number):

[image: table of differences]

This sequence could be generated as such (pseudocode):

```
for i=1 to r:
  output 0

for m=0, 1, …
  for k=1 to (r-1):
    for d=1 to r^m:
      for i=0 to (r-1):
        output (r-1) * (r+1)^m * (k - i)
```

If you store these values in a list/array, then `n - arr[n]` would get you the reversed form of `n`.  Now, to "mathematically golf" this, we'd ideally want a closed-form expression that gives us the n:th value in the sequence, so that we could have a closed-form expression for solving the entire task.  Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find such an expression... but it *looks* like it should be possible. :(

So yeah, not so much a code-golf as a mathematical curiosity, but if there is a closed-form expression of the above sequence it might actually be useful in proper PL golf submissions.

Answer (score 7):

## Haskell, <del>28</del> 24 characters

```
f=read.reverse.show.(+0)
```

Comment: How about `f=read.reverse.show.(+0)`?

Comment: `(+0)`: Legit man! Though technically you don't need the `.(+0)` at all, as `f` would be more polymorphic than what the problem requires (it is allowed to return a 'similarly typed' output). I would shave off those 5 characters.

Answer (score 6):

## Ruby (14)

```
x = 13456
x.to_s.reverse
```

Comment: "no" is undefined. I think you meant to put "x" there.

Comment: 123456.to_s.reverse is even shorter.

Comment: @mmdemirbas - thanks for fixing the typo

Comment: Needs to be `.to_s.reverse.to_i` to comply with spec.

Comment: A number that starts with 0 doesnt seem to work. 
0112.to_s.reverse.to_i
 => 47

Comment: @Joel A "number starting with 0", in ruby, is **octal**. I.e. `0112 == 74`. So unless you make a fundamental change to the ruby language, I think that's outside of scope.

Comment: Also, you can shave an extra digit off, with: `x.digits.join.to_i`

Answer (score 6):

**Scala - 33 Chars**

```
def r(a:Int)=(a+"").reverse.toInt
```

Comment: +1 for scala, nice to see something else than python/ruby/perl

Comment: This will fail on negative Int. -123 should return -321

Answer (score 6):

### Python 3+

#### Function form: 28 characters

```
r=lambda i:int(str(i)[::-1])
```

#### (Sub)program form: 25 characters

```
print(input()[::-1])
```

I consider some of the other Python examples to be cheating, or at least cheap, due to using hardcoded input and/or not fully satisfying the requirements.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to convert a number a string, then reverse the string and then convert that string back to number. This kind of feature is probably available in all language. If you are looking for a more mathematical method then this might help:

```
int n = 76543;
int r = 0;

while (n > 0) {
    r *= 10;
    r += n % 10;
    n /= 10;
}
```

Comment: Mine is absolutely the same (:

Comment: Ya, only difference is your code looks like Python.

Comment: This method overflow's on languages with limited precision. try `1111111119`

Answer (score 5):

### Golfscript, 5 chars

```
`-1%~
```

This takes an argument on the stack and leaves the result on the stack. I'm exploiting the "subprogram" option in the spec: if you insist on a function, that's four chars more leaving it on the stack:

```
{`-1%~}:r
```

Comment: I think you must've meant `\`-1%~` rather than `\`-1$~` (and I've taken the liberty of editing your answer to say so).

Answer (score 5):

In shell scripting :

```
  echo "your number"|rev
```

Hope this was useful :)

Comment: good one! didn't know bash was capable to that also!

Comment: I guess technically it *does* return a similarly-typed "number"... could be shortened further with `rev<<<yournumber`, e.g. `rev<<<132` (for bash/zsh, not per POSIX though)

Comment: Just `rev` is enough, the question doesn't say it **has** to be a function. You could compare `rev` to a built-in function, even though it's not one.

Comment: this is invalid: 'rev' is not a builtin, but an external program call.

Comment: 67 Bytes pure POSIX shell: X=$1;while [ $X != 0 ];do Y=$((Y*10+X%10));X=$((X/10));done;echo $Y

Answer (score 3):

Kinda late but

### APL, 3

```
⍎⌽⍞
```

If you insists on a function

```
⍎∘⌽∘⍕
```

Comment: Well looks like I couldn't spot a duplicate above...(due to it being on the 2nd page)

Comment: I'm sad, that nobody gave brainfu*k or whitespace solution :( (one more vote and you're on the first page )

Comment: @KirilKirov I've a brainfu*k solution : http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32826/24829

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 14 bytes

```
IntegerReverse
```

This is not competing, because this function was only added in last week's 10.3 release, but for completeness I thought I'd add the only ever (I think?) built-in for this task.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you mean by short (javascript):

```
alert(String(123).split('').reverse().join('')),
```

Comment: this is short for sure :)

Comment: `alert((''+123).split('').reverse().join(''));`

Comment: Why not `alert(prompt().split('').reverse().join(''));` ?

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following in Java. Note that this converts to String and back and is not a mathematical solution.

```
public class test {
    public static int reverseInt(int i) {
        return Integer.valueOf((new StringBuffer(String.valueOf(i))).reverse().toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 1234;
        System.out.println("reverse("+i+") -> " + reverseInt(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a mathematical solution. Mathematics is not numbers is not arithmetics. Mathematics also deals with strings of symbols. And in this special case, the conversion to and from string is just conversion to and from base-10.

Comment: What I meant by "not a mathematical solution" is that we're not doing any math ourselves. The methods are doing all of the parsing and mathematics for us. As opposed to e.g. Kiril Kirov's answer.

Comment: Will Overflow...

Answer (score 2):

## Lua

Numbers and strings are interchangeable, so this is trivial

```
string.reverse(12345)
```

Answer (score 2):

This one *ACTUALLY* takes an input, unlike some of the rest:

```
print`input()`[::-1]
```

Python btw.

Answer (score 2):

### Actionscript

43 characters. num as the parameter to the function:

```
num.toString().split('').reverse().join('')
```

Answer (score 2):

## Groovy

```
r={"$it".reverse() as BigDecimal}

assert r(1234) == 4321
assert r(345678987654567898765) == 567898765456789876543
assert r(345346457.24654654) == 45645642.754643543
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 11 chars

The `p` flag is needed for this to work, included in the count.

Usage:

```
$ echo 76543 | perl -pE '$_=reverse'
```

Comment: I count 10 chars

Comment: The `p` flag is included in the count

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure (42 chars)

```
#(->> % str reverse(apply str)read-string)
```

Example usage:

```
(#(->> % str reverse(apply str)read-string) 98321)
```

returns 12389

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp - 60 chars

```
(first(list(parse-integer(reverse(write-to-string '4279)))))
```

will get you 9724.

Comment: Why `(first(list`? `parse-integer` already returns the number.

Answer (score 2):

## K, 3 bytes:

```
.|$
```

Evaluate (`.`) the reverse (`|`) of casting to a string (`$`).

Usage example:

```
  .|$76543
34567
```

Answer (score 2):

## [rs](https://github.com/kirbyfan64/rs), 20 bytes

```
#
+#(.*)(.)/\2#\1
#/
```

Technically, this doesn't count (rs was created earlier this year), but I didn't see any other regex-based answers, and I thought this was neat.

[Live demo.](http://kirbyfan64.github.io/rs/index.html?script=%23%0A%2B%23(.*)(.)%2F%5C2%23%5C1%0A%23%2F&input=34567)

### Explanation:

```
#
```

Insert a pound character at the beginning of the string. This is used as a marker.

```
+#(.*)(.)/\2#\1
```

Continuously prepend the last character of the main string to the area before the marker until there are no characters left.

```
#/
```

Remove the marker.

Answer (score 2):

### mIRC 4.45 (35 Bytes)

```
$regsubex(12,/(.)/g,$mid(\A,-\n,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

this is AS3 code, so you may need to make slight changes

```
function reverseData ( inData:String ):* {
    var ar1 = inData.split(''); //Takes string value, split each digit into an array

    var ar2 = ar1.reverse(); //Inverses the array direction 
    /* //OR (if not supported) [not AS3]
    var ar2 = new Array();
    for( var i:int = (ar1.length - 1); i > 0; i++ ) {
        ar2.push( ar1[i] );
    }
    */

    var result = ar2.join();
    return result;
}
```

It should work for a string equavalent (that should be easy to typecast)

For a javascript example...

```
function flip( inData ) {
    return ( parseInt( (inData + '').split('').reverse().join('') ) );
}

alert( flip(123) );
```

Answer (score 1):

### C#

```
int reversed = Convert.ToInt32(String.Join<char>(null, 76543.ToString().Reverse()));
```

Comment: `int.Parse` should be shorter.

Comment: An anonymous user proposed editing this to `int reversed = int.Parse(string.Join("", ("" + 76543).Reverse()));`

Answer (score 1):

## Perl (19 chars)

Simple:

`$x=reverse (98765);`

Answer (score 1):

**k4 - 6 characters**

```
"I"$|$
```

Examples:

```
  "I"$|$76543
34567
  "I"$|$98765
56789
```

Explanation from right to left:
("I"$ = cast to integer)(| = reverse)($ = convert to string)

Comment: It's possible to use `.` (eval) instead of `"I"$`, i.e. `.|$`.

Answer (score 1):

## Java

```java
""+new StringBuilder(""+i).reverse();
```

Answer (score 1):

### in Q (20 characters)

```
f:{"I"$reverse -3!x}
```

Sample Usage:

```
q)f 89478237
73287498
```

Use the k version of reverse (wrapped in parentheses) to make it shorter

```
{"I"$(|:) -3!x}
```

also just define it as a lambda to take 2 chars off for a total of 15

Answer (score 1):

### Bash (15)

```
read a;rev<<<$a
```

As a number of other entries do, '01234' becomes '43210' and '2340' becomes '0432'; i.e. in Python terms it does `print reverse(raw_input())`. If behaviour like `print int(reverse(str(int(raw_input()))))` is expected, it is a bit longer:

#### Takes care of trailing zeroes (36)

```
read a;sed s.^0*..\;s.0*$..<<<$a|rev
```

Comment: I think right count is **`3`**: `rev` alone will suffice

Comment: “Write a function” – So I think the shortest solution is still 15 characters, but this way: `r(){ rev<<<$1;}`. (And even that is kind of cheating as the complete solutions is `r(){ return \`rev<<<$1\`;}`.)

Comment: @manatwork Shorter versions: ``r()(rev<<<$1)`` or ``r()(exit `rev<<<$1`)``.

Comment: Cool trick, @user23013.

Comment: `str(int(raw_input()))` really? [Python 2] [`str(int(input()))`] [from your example `print int(reverse(str(int(raw_input()))))`]

Answer (score 1):

## ruby (26)

The existing ruby answer wasn't a function/lambda, so here goes:

```
f=->i{i.to_s.reverse.to_i}
```

Answer (score 1):

**BaCon**

```
PRINT REVERSE$(STR$(76543))
```

Replace 76543 with any number.

Answer (score 1):

### Brainfuck, 11

```
>,[>,]<[.<]
```

Comment: This accepts any string, not just numbers (ASCII 48-57).

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth (3 chars)

Try it [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=v_z&input=76543&debug=0)

```
v_z
```

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, <s>35</s> <s>32</s> 31 (or 28) bytes

Takes input from the calculator's answer variable, which is whatever was last evaluated (like `_` in the interactive python shell).

```
fPart(.1int(Ans10^(seq(A,A,~int(log(Ans+.5)),not(Ans
sum(Ans10^(cumSum(1 or Ans
```

`10^(` is <kbd>2ND</kbd><kbd>LOG</kbd> and `~` is <kbd>( - )</kbd>, next to ENTER. Everything else can be found in the <kbd>2ND</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> catalog.

---

If the program doesn't have to handle the possibility of 0 as input, it can be reduced to 28 bytes by changing `~int(log(Ans+.5)),not(Ans` to `~int(log(Ans)),0`.
Credit goes partially to [Thomas Kwa](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39328/thomas-kwa) for helping to golf this.

Comment: Doesn't work with 0; you could easily fix this by replacing `log(Ans)` with `log(Ans+.5)` and `int(` with `iPart(`. The shortest I found in a few minutes with a forwards list of digits was `fPart(.1int(Ans10^(seq(A,A,~int(log(Ans)),0:sum(Ans10^(cumSum(1 or Ans`; this can probably be improved. Overall, good work!

Comment: @ThomasKwa yep, using 0 for the end argument throws ERR:INCREMENT. You're right about `not(Ans`, though.

Answer (score 1):

## ES6 Javascript, 31 bytes

```
x=>[...x+''].reverse().join('')
```

Comment: You could save 2 bytes by using .join\`\`  instead of .join('').
Also, what do you mean with that comment: "This doesn't assume `b` is an integer."

Answer (score 1):

C++:

```
int reverse(int number, int number1, int number2){std::vector<int> v; v.push_back(number); v.push_back(number1); v.push_back(number2); std::cout << v[2] << v[1] << v[0]; return 0;}
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf letsch! It is customary to include the byte count along with your submission, as this question is a [tag:code-golf]. You might want to format your header as such: `# C++, <number of bytes> bytes`

Comment: Adding to what Conor said, you should also attempt to make your code as short as possible since this is a code golf competition. You could start by removing unnecessary whitespace and using single letter names.

Answer (score 0):

**Scheme, 75 characters**

```
(string->number(list->string(reverse(string->list(number->string 76543)))))
```

Comment: You can probably remove all the spaces but the last one.

Comment: Count in bytes, please.

Answer (score 0):

## k3, 4 chars

```
0$|$

0$|$76543 \-> gives 34567
```

See also [the K4 solution here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/3600/3910). The only difference (saving two chars) is that `0$` converts to int.

Answer (score 0):

### PHP, 37

```
<?function f($n){return strrev($n);}
```

### C, 44

```
x;m(n){for(;n;x=x*10+n%10,n/=10);return x;}
```

Comment: Neither of these are functions, as specified.

Comment: @KevinReid Rectified!

Answer (score 0):

**R (35 characters)**

```
> cat(rev(strsplit("12345","")[[1]]))
5 4 3 2 1
```

With [help](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/6496912#6496912) from my friends in R chat.

Comment: `12345`->`54321`, not `12345`->`5 4 3 2 1`.

Answer (score 0):

### Game Maker Language, 44

Replace 12345 with whatever number or variable you want:

```
n=12345while(n>0){r=r*10+(n mod 10)n div 10}
```

If you want to prompt for user input, use this **56** character long code instead:

```
n=get_string('','')while(n>0){r=r*10+(n mod 10)n div 10}
```

In both pieces of code, the reverse number is stored in `r`

Comment: The question specifically asks for "a function (or equivalent subprogram)" which takes "a single integer valued argument". Neither of your code snippets meet that spec.

Comment: @PeterTaylor They're assumed to be scripts (function equivalents).

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, <s>61</s>,23

Using the string reversing technique. `digitToInt` is available from the `Data.Char` library, and of course this code would be shorter if we'd be able to assume if `Data.Char` already was available.

```
-- original version 61 chars
foldl1((+).(*)10).map(Data.Char.digitToInt)$reverse$show 1234

--bonus foldonly version, 67 chars
foldl1((+).(*)10).foldl(flip((:).Data.Char.digitToInt))[]$show 1234

--FireFly's suggestion: 23 chars. Note that read's return type is `a`
-- so you might want to tack on a +1 on ghci etc so `Int` can be derived.
read.reverse.show$1234
```

Comment: Hm, why not `read` it back after reversing? I.e. `read.reverse.show$1234`.

Comment: hmm for some silly reason I thought read had to do with IO monads. You're right, read would work.

Comment: Added it. fold was more fun though :)

Answer (score 0):

**Groovy 32**

```
def r(n){print ((n+"").reverse())}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Rebol, 29

```
f: func[n][do reverse mold n]
```

Usage example in Rebol console:

```
>> f 76543
== 34567
```

If you only wanted this to work on integer input then....

```
f: func [n [integer!]] [do reverse mold n]
```

Answer (score 0):

## TI-BASIC, <strike>58</strike> 54

```
Input N:0:While N>0:Ans+E3fpart(N,10:N/10→N:End:Ans
```

**Usage**

```
prgmREVERSE
?598028
          820895
            Done
```

Answer (score 0):

**POWERSHELL, 25**

```
-join(Read-Host)[-1..-9]
```

a longer version to take arbitrary input , 36

```
-join($a=Read-Host)[-1..-$a.length]
```

usage

```
PS C:\> -join(Read-Host)[-1..-9]
123456789
987654321
PS C:\>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Julia, 23

```
r(x)=int(reverse("$x"))
```

**$** interpolates an argument (or the result of a function) into a string, denoted by the double quotes. **int()** automatically deletes leading zeroes.

Example:

```
julia> x=1234567890;r(x)
987654321
```

or

```
julia> r(1234567890)
987654321
```

Answer (score 0):

## C# - 58

I think we need more C#

```
int.Parse(string.Concat(Enumerable.Reverse(x.ToString())))
```

Comment: The spec requires a function or equivalent subprogram (a lambda would probably be acceptable, but a statement isn't); and it requires the return value to be similarly typed to the input (i.e. you're missing an `int.Parse` or a `Convert.ToInt32`).

Comment: @CoolerRanch still a statement I think

Answer (score 0):

### Burlesque, 2 bytes

Certain built-ins treat numbers as list of digits. The reverse built-in for example treats integers as a list of digits and thus reverses integers.

```
blsq ) 76543<-
34567
```

(For characters `<-`  switches case).

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 3 bytes (non-competing)

```
VPU
```

This uses [release 10.1.0](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL) of the language/compiler, which is the current version at the time of writing.

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=VlBV&input=MTMyMzQ0Njc4)

#### Explanation

```
V   % implicitly input a number and convert to string
P   % flip
U   % convert to number and implicitly display
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 26 bytes

```
print int(`input()`[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 33 bytes

I decided to make a function instead of hardcoding it.

```
def r(n):print(int(str(n)[::-1]))
```

The code is pretty self-explanatory.

Usage: `r(12345)`

Answer (score 0):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, <s>35</s> 34 bytes

```sql
SELECT 0+REVERSE(:1||'')FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score -1):

## JavaScript (ES6) 35

`a=b=>b.split("").reverse().join("")`

Comment: This doesn't assume `b` is an integer.