# Most creative way to reverse a positive integer

Tags: popularity-contest

Provided an input as an unsigned integer:

```
13457
```

Your function/subroutine should return:

```
75431
```

Since this is a popularity contest, be creative. Creative solutions use unusual or clever techniques to accomplish given task.

Constraints:

- You cannot use arrays.
- You cannot use strings.
- No RTL Override (`&#8238`)

Brownie points for using creative arithmetics.

Since this is a popularity contest, I suggest not using the modulo (`%`) operator in your code.

**About Leading zeroes:**

If the input is:

```
12340
```

Then the output:

```
4321
```

would be acceptable.

Comment: Nope, uint all the way.

Comment: Unicode can be embedded in other contexts than just HTML. That RTL override codepoint could appear *anywhere*

Comment: @Gareth I updated the question.

Comment: Is it a duplicate of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2823/shortest-way-to-reverse-a-number ?

Comment: @microbian No, that one was code-golf. This one is popularity-contest.

Comment: You probably need more exclusions if you want to see genuine creativity. e.g. Database tables, lists in languages where a list functions like an array.

Comment: Can we use python generator objects?

Comment: By "cannot use strings", do you mean that there cannot be any strings, or that we cannot use strings to reverse the integer?

Comment: You can use generators @JayanthKoushik.
No strings *at all*.

Comment: @Gareth Your comment freaked me out a little. "Did I really post something an hour ago??" :-)

Comment: @Gareth How is this possible? I am so confused...

Comment: @JonathanVanMatre What do you suggest to open it up more? Should I forbid the use of modulus, or something like that?

Comment: People will be ticked if you start changing rules now.  It seems to be going fine to me, just run your next challenge through the sandbox first: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/proposed-questions-sandbox-mark-ix

Comment: What if `1230` is the input? Are we allowed to output `321`? (Otherwise, Strings are necessary).

Comment: @Quincunx not really, see my answer

Comment: The question is now ambiguous? What do you mean by 'suggest not using modulo'?  Can we use it or can we not?  Be clear.  Also how can the rule be changed all of a sudden where most of the answers so far are using that modulo.  By prohibiting modulo solutions will try to use arrays indirectly, like through lists and similar.  Is that allowed?

Comment: The *leading zeros* example doesn't make much sense since it doesn't reverse.

Comment: @Howard Sorry :( updated.

Comment: @microbian It is **suggested** not to use modulo, because that is the obvious solution, and this is a popularity contest.

Comment: and everyone uses modulo!

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic because this lacks an objective validity criterion - "be creative" is subjective.

Comment: @Mego [But two people voted to keep it open, and I don't understand why](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/close/30041)

Comment: @Mego Man, the popularity-contest tag itself uses the word "creativity" as criteria. I don't know how 2 years later this question could be decided to be off topic.

Comment: @duci9y We have since decided, as a community, that popcons must have objective validity criteria for what qualifies as a valid answer, and what specific qualities make an answer better than another. Relevant meta post: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8093/45941

Answer (score 49, accepted):

### Mathematica, no modulo!

```m
n = 14627;
length = Ceiling[Log[10, n]];
img = Rasterize[n, RasterSize -> 400, ImageSize -> 400];
box = Rasterize[n, "BoundingBox", RasterSize -> 400, ImageSize -> 400];
width = box[[1]]; height = box[[3]];
ToExpression[
 TextRecognize[
  ImageAssemble[
   ImageTake[img, {1, height}, #] & /@ 
    NestList[# - width/length &, {width - width/length, width}, 
     length - 1]]]]
```

Let's break it down.

First we use some "creative arithmetics" to find out how many digits are in the number: `length = Ceiling[Log[10, n]];`

Next, we Rasterize the number to a nice large image:

[image: honking big rasterized number]

Now we query for the bounding box of that image, and populate the width and height (actually using the baseline offset instead of the image height, because MM adds some whitespace below the baseline in the image).

Next, NestList recursively subtracts the width of the image divided by the length of the string to enable ImageTake to pluck characters from the end of the image one by one, and those are reassembled by ImageAssemble to this image:

[image: honking big reversed number]

Then we pass that on to the TextRecognize function for optical character recognition, which at this image size and rasterization quality is able to impeccably recognize the final output and give us the integer:

```
72641
```

Logarithms and OCR - It's like chocolate and peanut butter!

#### New and improved

This version pads out the number to deal with the obstinate behavior of TextRecognize with small numbers, and then subtracts out the pad at the end. This even works for single-digit numbers!

Though, why you would run a reverse routine on a single number is a mystery to me. But just for the sake of completeness, I even made it work for inputs of zero and one, which would normally break because the floored log doesn't return 1 for them.

```m
n = 1;
pad = 94949;
length = If[n == 1 || n == 0, 1, Ceiling[Log[10, n]]];
img = Rasterize[n + (pad*10^length), RasterSize -> 400, 
   ImageSize -> 400];
padlength = length + 5;
box = ImageDimensions[img];
width = box[[1]]; height = box[[2]];
reversed = 
  ImageResize[
   ImageAssemble[
    ImageTake[img, {1, height}, #] & /@ 
     NestList[# - width/padlength &, {width + 1 - width/padlength, 
       width}, padlength - 1]], 200];
recognized = ToExpression[TextRecognize[reversed]];
(recognized - pad)/10^5
```

Comment: Beat me to it. You've got my vote!! [but I was going to use C#]

Comment: `TextRegognize` isn't working for small numbers. And you have typo in `height = b[[3]];`. Also check my answer too, please! :)

Comment: Another problem with `TextRecognize`, is that it returns a String, which isn't allowed and also you need to convert it back to number.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the typo...I was making the variable names more reader friendly before submitting and missed one. Also threw in the missing ToExpression. And I posted a revision that deals with the small numbers problem all the way to single digits.

Comment: Wow… that's elaborate!

Comment: That's probably one of the more creative solutions I've seen for these type of questions. I wouldn't think to consider OCR :p

Comment: I take admonitions to be creative to heart.  :)

Answer (score 41):

### Perl/LuaTeX/Tesseract

The following Perl script reads the number as command line argument, e.g.:

`1234567890`

The following Perl script prints the number via LuaTeX. A virtual font is created on the fly that mirrors the digits horizontally.

> [image: temp0.png]

Then the whole number is again mirrored horizontally:

> [image: temp1.png]

The final image is reread via OCR (tesseract):

`0987654321`

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
$^W=1;

# Get the number as program argument or use a fixed number with all digits.
$_ = shift // 1234567890;

$\="\n"; # append EOL, when printing

# Catch negative number
exit print "NaUI (Not an Unsigned Integer)" if $_ < 0;

# Catch number with one digit.
exit ! print if ($_ = $= = $_) < 10;

undef $\;

# Write TeX file for LuaTeX
open(OUT, '>', 'temp.tex') or die "!!! Error: Cannot write: $!\n";
print OUT<<"END_PRINT";
% Catcode setting for iniTeX (a TeX format is not needed)
\\catcode`\{=1
\\catcode`\}=2
\\def\\mynumber{$_}
END_PRINT
print OUT<<'END_PRINT';
\directlua{tex.enableprimitives('',tex.extraprimitives())}
\pdfoutput=1 % PDF output
% move origin to (0,0)
\pdfhorigin=0bp
\pdfvorigin=0bp
% magnify the result by 5
\mag=5000

% Create virtual font, where the digits are mirrored
\directlua{
  callback.register('define_font',
    function (name,size)
      if name == 'cmtt10-digits' then
        f = font.read_tfm('cmtt10',size)
        f.name = 'cmtt10-digits'
        f.type = 'virtual'
        f.fonts = {{ name = 'cmtt10', size = size }}
        for i,v in pairs(f.characters) do
          if (string.char(i)):find('[1234567890]') then
            v.commands = {
               {'right',f.characters[i].width},
               {'special','pdf: q -1 0 0 1 0 0 cm'},
               {'char',i},
               {'right',-f.characters[i].width},
               {'special','pdf: Q'},
            }
          else
            v.commands = {{'char',i}}
          end
        end
      else
        f = font.read_tfm(name,size)
      end
      return f
    end
  )
}

% Activate the new font
\font\myfont=cmtt10-digits\relax
\myfont

% Put the number in a box and add a margin (for tesseract)
\dimen0=5bp % margin
\setbox0=\hbox{\kern\dimen0 \mynumber\kern\dimen0}
\ht0=\dimexpr\ht0+\dimen0\relax
\dp0=\dimexpr\dp0+\dimen0\relax
\pdfpagewidth=\wd0
\pdfpageheight=\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax

% For illustration only: Print the number with the reflected digits:
\shipout\copy0 % print the number with the reflected digits

% Final version on page 2: Print the box with the number, again mirrored
\shipout\hbox{%
  \kern\wd0
  \pdfliteral{q -1 0 0 1 0 0 cm}%
  \copy0
  \pdfliteral{Q}%
}

% End job, no matter, whether iniTeX, plain TeX or LaTeX
\csname @@end\endcsname\end
END_PRINT

system "luatex --ini temp.tex >/dev/null";
system qw[convert temp.pdf temp%d.png];
system "tesseract temp1.png temp >/dev/null 2>&1";

# debug versions with output on console
#system "luatex --ini temp.tex";
#system qw[convert temp.pdf temp%d.png];
#system "tesseract temp1.png temp";

# Output the result, remove empty lines
open(IN, '<', 'temp.txt') or die "!!! Error: Cannot open: $!\n";
chomp, print while <IN>;
print "\n";
close(IN);

__END__
```

Comment: +1 for TeX. We need more TeX answers!

Answer (score 25):

## **Brainfuck**

Basically, it is just an input-reversing program.

```
,[>,]<[.<]
```

UPD: As [Sylwester](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11290/sylwester) pointed out in comments, in the classical Brainfuck interpreters/compilers (without possibility to going left from zero point in the memory array) this program would not work in the absence of '>' at the beginning, so the more stable version is:

```
>,[>,]<[.<]
```

Comment: Shortest Bf program I've ever seen. Also, really neat.

Comment: Without a `>` in the beginning to make a zero cell before the data this won't work in many interpreters/compilers.

Comment: That's a good point, @Sylwester, but in [classical Brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) all the cells are set to 0 by default and you are starting with cell number 0, which is the first element of the memory array used, so it should not make a problem in a classical case, which is important.

Comment: @Danek true, all the cells are initialized to zero and the first thing you do is to read the first digit into the very first cell. `[.<]` has no zero cell to stop at because of that and will fail. Error from `bf -n rev1.bf` is `Error: Out of range! Youwanted to '<' below the first cell.`. If you compile you get a `segfault` perhaps.

Comment: @Sylwester, oh yeah, that's true! I'll add it to my answer, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Nit Well, you must be new here!

Comment: +1 too even if BF is all about arrays so I'm not sure it fits the rule *Do not use array*

Comment: @Michael, Brainfuck's array is just the only possibility to store data and, consequently, to access the input stream, so I believe it is OK.

Comment: @Nit echo is much shorter: `,[.,]`

Comment: @Mig Technically, some implementations for BF run with a pointer pointing to an allocated region of space. Instead of incrementing the index of the array, the pointer is incremented, etc.

Comment: @Nit And technically, it's a Tape, not an Array.

Answer (score 20):

## Haskell

```haskell
reverseNumber :: Integer -> Integer
reverseNumber x = reverseNumberR x e 0
    where e = 10 ^ (floor . logBase 10 $ fromIntegral x)

reverseNumberR :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
reverseNumberR 0 _ _ = 0
reverseNumberR x e n = d * 10 ^ n + reverseNumberR (x - d * e) (e `div` 10) (n + 1)
    where d = x `div` e
```

No arrays, strings, or modulus.

Also, I know we're not supposed to use lists or strings, but I love how short it is when you do that:

```haskell
reverseNumber :: Integer -> Integer
reverseNumber = read . reverse . show
```

Comment: A bunch of site regulars had maxed out their voting for the day, so have patience.  :)

Answer (score 18):

I suppose *someone* has to be the partypooper.

## Bash

```
$ rev<<<[Input]
```

```
$ rev<<<321
123
$ rev<<<1234567890
0987654321
```

Size limitations depend on your shell, but you'll be fine within reason.

Comment: well played sir. well played

Comment: How is that not a string?

Comment: This *might* be a string. Are you sure bash takes input as integers when possible?

Comment: Everything is a string in Bash unless declared otherwise using for example `declare -i`. Compare `foo=089` and `declare -i foo=089` (invalid octal number).

Comment: As per the comment by @l0b0 this answer is invalid.

Comment: And even if `bash` thought it was a number, `rev` sure as hell doesn't. :)

Comment: `rev` operates on the data as a string: https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/text-utils/rev.c#L169

Answer (score 18):

### C++

```
/* 
A one-liner RECUrsive reveRSE function. Observe that the reverse of a 32-bit unsigned int
can overflow the type (eg recurse (4294967295) = 5927694924 > UINT_MAX), thus the 
return type of the function should be a 64-bit int. 

Usage: recurse(n)
*/

int64_t recurse(uint32_t n, int64_t reverse=0L)
{
    return n ? recurse(n/10, n - (n/10)*10 + reverse * 10) : reverse;
}
```

Comment: Would be cooler with `?:`

Comment: @mniip Good idea

Comment: + 1 Brilliant. Wish there were more upvotes.

Comment: Kudos for catching the overflow case.

Answer (score 14):

### Javascript

**EDIT** : Since there is a suggestion to not use `%` operator, I use a little trick now.

I know this is not a code-golf, but there is no reason to make it longer.

```
function r(n){v=0;while(n)v=n+10*(v-(n=~~(n/10)));return v}
```

`r(13457)` returns `75431`

Moreover, it's a lot faster than *string* method (`n.toString().split('').reverse().join('')`) :

[image]

[==> JSPerf report <==](http://jsperf.com/reverse-number)

Comment: What about using `~~` instead of `Math.floor`?

Comment: Yes that would be shorter, but less understandable.

Comment: Isn't this the textbook integer-reversal method? I think I've written this algorithm for homework.

Comment: As with the comment above, this is just the standard integer reversal algorithm. As far as I can see the creative part is just the usage of `~~` instead of `Math.floor` (the change suggested by @Victor)

Comment: +1 for performance testing. all the great creative minds do performance testing early and often.  :D

Comment: +1 ... although the comparison ain't fair since `reverse()` works for everything.

Answer (score 10):

### Python

*Not sure if this implementation qualifies for creative math*

*Also % operator was not used per se, though one might argue that divmod does the same, but then then the Question needs to be rephrased :-)*

**Implementation**

```
r=lambda n:divmod(n,10)[-1]*10**int(__import__("math").log10(n))+r(n /10)if n else 0
```

**demo**

```
>>> r(12345)
54321
>>> r(1)
1
```

**How does it work?**

*This is a recursive divmod solution*
*This solution determines the least significant digit and then pushes it to the end of the number.*

**Yet Another Python Implementation**

```
def reverse(n):
    def mod(n, m):
        return n - n / m * m
    _len = int(log10(n))
    return n/10**_len + mod(n, 10)*10**_len + reverse(mod(n, 10**_len)/10)*10 if n and _len else n
```

**How does it work?**

*This is a recursive solution which swaps the extreme digits from the number*

```
Reverse(n) = Swap_extreme(n) + Reverse(n % 10**int(log10(n)) / 10) 
             ; n % 10**log10(n) / n is the number without the extreme digits
             ; int(log10(n)) is the number of digits - 1
             ; n % 10**int(log10(n)) drops the most significant digit
             ; n / 10 drops the least significant digit

Swap_extreme(n) = n/10**int(log10(n)) + n%10*10**int(log10(n))
             ; n%10 is the least significant digit
             ; n/10**int(log10(n)) is the most significant digit
```

**Example Run**

```
reverse(123456) = 123456/10^5 + 123456 % 10 * 10^5 + reverse(123456 % 10 ^ 5 / 10)
                = 1           + 6 * 10 ^ 5 + reverse(23456/10)
                = 1           + 600000     + reverse(2345)
                = 600001 + reverse(2345)
reverse(2345)   = 2345/10^3 + 2345 % 10 * 10^3 + reverse(2345 % 10 ^ 3 / 10)
                = 2         + 5 * 10^3 + reverse(345 / 10)
                = 2         + 5000     + reverse(34)
                = 5002                 + reverse(34)
reverse(34)     = 34/10^1 + 34 % 10 * 10^1 + reverse(34 % 10 ^ 1 / 10)
                = 3       + 40             + reverse(0)
                = 43 + reverse(0)
reverse(0)      = 0

Thus

reverse(123456) = 600001 + reverse(2345)
                = 600001 + 5002 + reverse(34)
                = 600001 + 5002 + 43 + reverse(0)
                = 600001 + 5002 + 43 + 0
                = 654321
```

Comment: It does. *+5 brownie points*.

Comment: @downvoter: Can you please respond what is wrong with this answer?

Comment: you, sir, deserve my thumbs up ...

Answer (score 9):

Just to be contrary, an overuse of the modulo operator:

```
unsigned int reverse(unsigned int n)
    {return n*110000%1099999999%109999990%10999900%1099000%100000;}
```

Note that this always reverses 5 digits, and 32 bit integers will overflow for input values more than 39045.

Answer (score 8):

## **C#**

Here's a way to do it without the Modulus (`%`) operator and just simple arithmetic.

```
int x = 12356;
int inv = 0;
while (x > 0)
{
    inv = inv * 10 + (x - (x / 10) * 10);
    x = x / 10;
}
return inv;
```

Comment: You have modulus, you simply defined it yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I know. We're just not supposed to use the `%` operator. :) I see what you mean though, my text was a little misleading.

Answer (score 7):

Bash

```
> fold -w1 <<<12345 | tac | tr -d '\n'
54321
```

Answer (score 6):

## C

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int r = 0, x;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    while (x > 0) {
        int y = x;
        x = 0;
        while (y >= 10) { y -= 10; ++x; }
        r = r*10 + y;
    }
    printf("%d\n", r);
}
```

No strings, arrays, modulus or division. Instead, division by repeated subtraction.

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica

Making an image out of number, reflecting it, partitioning it into the digits. Then there is two alternatives:

1. Compare each image of a reflected digit with prepared earlier images, replace it with the corresponding digit and construct the number out of this.
2. Reflect every digit separately, construct a new image, and pass it to the image recognition function.

I did both

```m
reflectNumber[n_?IntegerQ] := 
 ImageCrop[
  ImageReflect[
   Image@Graphics[
     Style[Text@NumberForm[n, NumberSeparator -> {".", ""}], 
      FontFamily -> "Monospace", FontSize -> 72]], 
   Left -> Right], {Max[44 Floor[Log10[n] + 1], 44], 60}]
reflectedDigits = reflectNumber /@ Range[0, 9];
reverse[0] := 0
reverse[n_?IntegerQ /; n > 0] := 
 Module[{digits}, 
  digits = ImagePartition[reflectNumber[1000 n], {44, 60}];
  {FromDigits[
    digits[[1]] /. (d_ :> # /; d == reflectedDigits[[# + 1]] & /@ 
       Range[0, 9])],
   ToExpression@
    TextRecognize[
     ImageAssemble[
      Map[ImageReflect[#, Left -> Right] &, digits, {2}]]]}]
reverse[14257893]
> {39875241, 39875241}
```

**EDIT**: Added padding of three zeroes, because `TextRecognise` works correctly only with integers > 999.

Comment: Kudos for the double reflection. Every good programmer should use reflection whenever possible. ;-) However, your first method doesn't work for your example on my system in MM9.

Comment: Now that's creative.

Comment: I got best results alternating 9 and 4 in my pad (all 9s or all 1s tended to give occasional OCR glitches), but that's probably down to the difference in fonts.

Answer (score 5):

## Lua

```lua
function assemble(n,...)
    if ... then
        return 10*assemble(...)+n
    end
    return 0
end
function disassemble(n,...)
    if n>0 then
        return disassemble(math.floor(n/10),n%10,...)
    end
    return ...
end
function reverse(n)
    return assemble(disassemble(n))
end
```

No arrays or strings used. The number is split into digits and reassembled using the arguments list.

Comment: Lua doesn't have arrays anyway. Has tables :P  Otherwise varargs are arrays

Comment: @Nowayz It has tables which can resemble arrays. Which is why I am not allowed to use them. And varargs aren't arrays :P

Comment: But you're using `%`! :P

Answer (score 5):

### Python2

Assumes "unsigned integer" is 32-bit

```
import math
import sys
a=input()
p=int(math.log(a, 10))
b=a
while b%10==0:
    sys.stdout.write('0') # if 1-char string is not allowed, use chr(48) instead
    b=b/10

if p==0:
    print a
elif p==1:
    print a%10*10+a/10
elif p==2:
    print a%10*100+a%100/10*10+a/100
elif p==3:
    print a%10*1000+a%100/10*100+a%1000/100*10+a/1000
elif p==4:
    print a%10*10000+a%100/10*1000+a%1000/100*100+a%10000/1000*10+a/10000
elif p==5:
    print a%10*100000+a%100/10*10000+a%1000/100*1000+a%10000/1000*100+a%100000/10000*10+a/100000
elif p==6:
    print a%10*1000000+a%100/10*100000+a%1000/100*10000+a%10000/1000*1000+a%100000/10000*100+a%1000000/100000*10+a/1000000
elif p==7:
    print a%10*10000000+a%100/10*1000000+a%1000/100*100000+a%10000/1000*10000+a%100000/10000*1000+a%1000000/100000*100+a%10000000/1000000*10+a/10000000
elif p==8:
    print a%10*100000000+a%100/10*10000000+a%1000/100*1000000+a%10000/1000*100000+a%100000/10000*10000+a%1000000/100000*1000+a%10000000/1000000*100+a%100000000/10000000*10+a/100000000
elif p==9:
    print a%10*1000000000+a%100/10*100000000+a%1000/100*10000000+a%10000/1000*1000000+a%100000/10000*100000+a%1000000/100000*10000+a%10000000/1000000*1000+a%100000000/10000000*100+a%1000000000/100000000*10+a/1000000000
```

When given input `1230`, it outputs `0321`.

Comment: I just saw the edit of modulus operator... should I delete this post?

Comment: I don't think you should delete it, because it is a suggestion to not use it, not a rule: `"Since this is a popularity contest, I suggest not using the modulus (%) operator in your code."`

Comment: Plus that huge if statement is practically ASCII art.

Answer (score 4):

### Postscript

```
/rev{0 exch{dup 10 mod 3 -1 roll 10 mul add exch 10 idiv dup 0 eq{pop exit}if}loop}def
```

No arrays, no strings, no variables.

```
gs -q -dBATCH -c '/rev{0 exch{dup 10 mod 3 -1 roll 10 mul add exch 10 idiv dup 0 eq{pop exit}if}loop}def 897251 rev ='
152798
```

The same without `mod` (which is just a shortcut, so no big difference):

```
/rev {
    0 exch {
        dup
        10 idiv dup
        3 1 roll 10 mul sub
        3 -1 roll 10 mul add exch 
        dup 0 eq {pop exit} if
    } loop
} def
```

Answer (score 4):

## **C**

In that the obvious solution is represented in a couple other languages, might as well post it in C.

**Golfed:**

```
r;main(n){scanf("%d",&n);for(;n;n/=10)r=r*10+n%10;printf("%d",r);}
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     int n, r = 0;
     scanf("%d", &n);
     for(;n;n/=10)
     { 
          r = r * 10 + n % 10;
     }
     printf("%d", r);
}
```

EDIT: Just saw the modulus edit.

**Golfed (no modulus):**

```
r;main(n){scanf("%d",&n);for(;n;n/=10)r=r*10+(n-10*(n/10));printf("%d",r);}
```

**Ungolfed (no modulus):**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     int n, r, m = 0;
     scanf("%d", &n);
     for(;n;n/=10)
     { 
          r=r*10+(n-10*(n/10));
     }
     printf("%d", r);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## C#

This uses no strings or arrays, but does use the .NET `Stack<T>` type (EDIT: originally used modulus operator; now removed)

```
public class IntegerReverser
{
    public int Reverse(int input)
    {
        var digits = new System.Collections.Generic.Stack<int>();
        int working = input;
        while (working / 10 > 0)
        {
            digits.Push(working - ((working / 10) * 10));
            working = working / 10;
        }
        digits.Push(working);
        int result = 0;
        int mult = 1;
        while (digits.Count > 0)
        {
            result += digits.Pop() * mult;
            mult *= 10;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## python (easily done in assembly)

Reverses the bits of a byte. Points for not doing the exact same thing everyone else did?

```
x = int(input("byte: "), 2)
x = ((x * 8623620610) & 1136090292240) % 1023
print("{0:b}".format(x).zfill(8))
```

example

```
byte: 10101010
01010101
```

Comment: Would it work for the sample input to produce the sample output?

Answer (score 4):

## Java

This is the this i've come up with, no strings, no arrays... not even variables (in Java I mind you):

```
public static int reverse(int n) {
    return n/10>0?(int)(modulo(n,10)*Math.pow(10, count(n)))+reverse(n/10):(int)(modulo(n,10)*Math.pow(10,count(n)));
}

public static int count(int i) {
    return (i = i/10)>0?count(i)+1:0;
}

public static int modulo(int i,int j) {
    return (i-j)>=0?modulo(i-j, j):i;
}
```

**EDIT** A more readable version

```
/** Method to reverse an integer, without the use of String, Array (List), and %-operator */
public static int reverse(int n) {
    // Find first int to display
    int newInt = modulo(n,10);
    // Find it's position
    int intPos = (int) Math.pow(10, count(n));
    // The actual value
    newInt = newInt*intPos;
    // Either add newInt to the recursive call (next integer), or return the found
    return (n/10>0) ? newInt+reverse(n/10) : newInt;
}

/** Use the stack, with a recursive call, to count the integer position */
public static int count(int i) {
    return (i = i/10)>0?count(i)+1:0;
}

/** A replacement for the modulo operator */
public static int modulo(int i,int j) {
    return (i-j)>=0?modulo(i-j, j):i;
}
```

Comment: Please make your code more readable, this is not code golf. Thank you.

Comment: This is my first attempt at this, i hope the updated version is better :-)

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you. Welcome to Code Golf. I'm new too. :)

Answer (score 3):

## PowerShell

A quick solution in PowerShell.
No arrays or strings used, either implicitly or explicitly.

```
function rev([int]$n) {
    $x = 0
    while ($n -gt 0) {
        $x = $x * 10
        $x += $n % 10
        $n = [int][math]::Floor($n / 10)
    }
    $x
}
```

Testing:

```
PS > rev(13457)
75431

PS > rev(rev(13457))
13457
```

Answer (score 3):

## C++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i,size;
    float num;
    char ch;
    cout<<"enter the number \t: ";
    cin>>num;
    ofstream outf("tmp.tmp");
    outf<<num;
    outf.close();
    ifstream inf("tmp.tmp");
    inf.seekg(0,ios::end);
    size=inf.tellg();
    inf.seekg(-1,ios::cur);
    cout<<"Reverse of it\t\t: ";
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        inf>>ch;
        if(ch!='0'||i!=0)
        cout<<ch;
        inf.seekg(-2,ios::cur);
    }
    inf.close();
            remove("tmp.tmp");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

#### OUTPUT

Three sample runs
[image]

Test with zeros

[image]

It too **reverses floating numbers!!!**

[image]

If you want **to run this code** then run it on your computer because it creates a temporary file during its run-time and I am not sure if online compilers would make a temporary file on your computer

Comment: Isn't writing to a file making it a string?

Comment: string is a combination of character with a null character at the end so, it is not a string but a combination of characters only

Comment: A string is a sequence of characters. Sorry, but this answer does not meet the constraints.

Comment: your definition to strings is wrong please go to this website (http://cs.stmarys.ca/~porter/csc/ref/c_cpp_strings.html) and read the last paragraph carefully.String is a combination of characters **ENDED WITH A '\0'**

Comment: That is just an implementation detail. The first few lines of the link you posted says, "The term string generally means an ordered sequence of characters, with a first character, a second character, and so on…"

Comment: char a={'a','b','c','d', **'\0'** };('a' is a string)    char a={'a','b','c','d'}; //'a' is a character combination but not a string.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are talking about C strings. I'm talking about strings in general. Your answer does not qualify.

Answer (score 2):

## ECMAScript 6

```
reverse=x=>{
    var k=-(l=(Math.log10(x)|0)),
        p=x=>Math.pow(10,x),
        s=x*p(l);
    for(;k;k++) s-=99*(x*p(k)|0)*p(l+k);
    return s
}
```

Then:

- `reverse(12345)` outputs `54321`
- `reverse(3240)` outputs `423`
- `reverse(6342975)` outputs `5792436`

Answer (score 2):

## [Fission](https://github.com/C0deH4cker/Fission)

```
$SX/
\S?L
K\O
```

This program reverses the input.

```
$ echo -n '12345' | fsn tac.fsn
54321
```

Comment: You just narrowly slip past the "Did the programming language exist before the question was asked?" test on this one. Fission looks like a cool entry to the esolang world - sort of "Befunge on acid with a shelf full of particle physics books." Nice!

Answer (score 2):

## FORTH

I think this is the opposite of popular... but using Forth is always creative...

Let's create a new word

```
: REV 
  BEGIN
    S->D 10 U/
    SWAP 1 .R
  DUP 0= UNTIL 
CR ;
```

Here, it uses word U/ that returns remainder and quotient, remainder is sent to output as number within a field 1 character long, until dividend is zero.
No string is used, at least until something is sent to video.
I do not use a modulo operator, instead I use integer division with remainder and quotient.
Let's try

```
12345 REV 54321
ok
```

[image: ZX Spectrum emulator]

Comment: Where do I get that emulator?

Comment: World of Spectrum has plenty of emulators listed here http://www.worldofspectrum.org/emulators.html

Answer (score 2):

## Turing Machine Code

Using the syntax from [here.](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html)

```
0 * * l 0
0 _ # r 2
2 # # r 2
2 0 # l A
2 1 # l B
2 2 # l C
2 3 # l D
2 4 # l E
2 5 # l F
2 6 # l G
2 7 # l H
2 8 # l I
2 9 # l J
2 _ _ l Z
A * * l A
A _ 0 l Q 
B * * l B
B _ 1 l Q 
C * * l C
C _ 2 l Q
D * * l D
D _ 3 l Q
E * * l E
E _ 4 l Q
F * * l F
F _ 5 l Q
G * * l G
G _ 6 l Q
H * * l H
H _ 7 l Q
I * * l I
I _ 8 l Q
J * * l J
J _ 9 l Q
Q # # r 2
Q * * r Q
Z # _ l Z
Z * * l ZZ
ZZ _ * r ZZZ
ZZ * * l ZZ
ZZZ 0 _ r ZZZ
ZZZ * * * halt
```

[Try it online!](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?2fe2a52485900fd0842811eab656e172)

Answer (score 1):

## Python

```
import itertools

def rev(n):
    l = next(m for m in itertools.count() if n/10**m == 0)
    return sum((n-n/10**(i+1)*10**(i+1))/10**i*10**(l-i-1) for i in range(l))
```

Comment: `rev(1230)` gives `321`. I suppose it should really give `0321`?

Comment: Is that wrong? If we are only dealing with numbers, not strings, then 0321 and 321 are equivalent right?

Comment: It should be 321 to my understanding.  The question disallowed using of strings.  So it should be 321.

Comment: I don't know... waiting for the OP's reply. I'm just pointing this out, not saying it's wrong. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

## C

```
#include <stdio.h>

int c(int n) {
    return !n ? 0 : 1+c(n/10);
}

int p(int n) {
    return !n ? 1 : 10*p(n-1);
}

int r(int n) {
    return !n ? 0 : n%10*p(c(n/10))+r(n/10);
}

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", r(13457));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Batch

Missed the part about not using strings - oh well.

```
@echo off
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion enableExtensions
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "ASCII_13=%%a"
set num=%~1
set cnum=%num%
set len=0
:c
if defined num set num=%num:~1%&set /a len+=1&goto :c
set /a len-=1
for /L %%a in (%len%,-1,0) do set /p "=!ASCII_13!!cnum:~%%a,1!"<nul
```

Answer (score 1):

**Python 2**

```
import math

def reverseNumber(num):
    length = int(math.ceil(math.log10(num)))
    reversed = 0

    for i in range(0, length):
        temp = num // math.pow(10, length - i - 1)
        num -= temp * math.pow(10, length - i - 1)
        reversed += int(temp * math.pow(10, i))

    return reversed

print reverseNumber(12345)
```

Answer (score 1):

### C#

```
private static int ReverseNumber(int forwardNumber)
{

    double forwardPower = 20;   //some number longer than Int32.MaxValue.Length
    double reversePower = 0;
    int reverseNumber=0;
    bool realNumberStarted=false;

    do
    {
        var tempInt= (int)(forwardNumber / Math.Pow(10, forwardPower));
        tempInt = (int)((((decimal)tempInt / 10) - (tempInt / 10))*10);
        if (tempInt>0 && !realNumberStarted)
        {
            realNumberStarted = true;
        }
        reverseNumber = reverseNumber+ tempInt * (int)Math.Pow(10, reversePower);
        if (realNumberStarted)
        {
            reversePower++;
        }

        forwardPower--;
    } while (forwardPower >=0);

    return reverseNumber;
}
```

Outputs

```
Console.WriteLine( ReverseNumber(12345));
Console.WriteLine(ReverseNumber(67584930));
```

---

```
54321
3948576
```

Answer (score 1):

## C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    uint32_t n = 0;
    scanf("%u", &n);

    while (n) {
        uint64_t o = (uint64_t) n * 3435973837u;
        uint32_t r = o >> 35;
        putchar(n - r * 10 + '0');
        n = o >> 35;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Convert division (with constant divisor) to multiplication. I used [this page](http://www.hackersdelight.org/magic.htm) to generate the factor.

The resulting code doesn't use `/` or `%` operators. Only `>>`, `*`, `+`, `-` are used.

#### References

- http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/labor-of-division-episode-i.html
- http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.33.1710
- http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.1.2556

Answer (score 1):

## C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned  next_p( unsigned p )
{
  unsigned  next =
    ( 8 & ((p << 1) & ((~p) << 2)) )     |
    ( 4 & (~p) )                         |
    ( 2 & ((p >> 2) | ((p >> 1) & p)) );
  
  return next;
}

unsigned  mAp( unsigned x, unsigned p )
{
  unsigned  the_rest = 0;
  
  if (x > 1)
    the_rest = mAp( x >> 1, next_p(p) );
  
  if (x & 1)
    return (the_rest < 10 - p) ? the_rest + p : the_rest + p - 10;
  else if (x)
    return  the_rest;
  else
    return 0;
}

unsigned  fumA( unsigned x )
{
  unsigned  v = mAp( x >> 1, 2 );
  
  if (x & 1)
    ++v;
  
  if (v < 10)
    return v;
  
  return fumA( v-10 );
}


unsigned  rflipper(unsigned x, unsigned *p)
{
  unsigned  y = 0;
  
  if (x >= 10)
    y = rflipper( x / 10, p );
  
  y += fumA(x) * *p;
  
  (*p) *= 10;
  
  return y;
}

unsigned  rflip(unsigned x)
{
  unsigned  p = 1;
  
  return rflipper(x, &p);
}


int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
  unsigned  i;
  
  if (argc < 2)
    {
      printf( "Useage:\n\t%s <positive integer>\n\n", argv[0] );
      return 0;
    }
  
  i = rflip(atoi(argv[1]));
  
  printf( "%d\n", i );
  
  return i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Extended BrainFuck](http://sylwester.no/ebf/)

```
;;; variables
:input
:flag
:zero

;;; macros
;; read byte with all EOF conventions 
;; + it also stops on linefeed
;; compatible BF interpreters translate CRLF => LF
;; so this would be portable
;; char value is one more than actual value
{read_byte
   $flag +
   $input ,
   +[-[10-[11+$flag-]]]
   >[@flag-$zero]
}

;; assumes current cell is empty
;; prints out a linefeed
{linefeed
   10+.
}

;; Assumes data starts to the left of current cell
;; prints until zero
{print_bytes_left
 <[.<]
}

;;; main program 
while more $input + 
( - 
  >@input    ;; shift variables to the right
  &read_byte ;; read in byte
)
&print_bytes_left
&linefeed
```

Since someone beat me to a BF answer I rewrote it in EBF and made it portable and compatible. This doesn't wrap cells, it stops when encontering any one of the 3 EOF indicators or a linefeed. In compatible interpreters CRLF is translated to just a LF so this should work on any interpreter.

Usage:

```
% bf ebf.bf < rev.ebf > rev.bf
% echo 2345 | bf -w rev.bf
5432
```

The resulting BrainFuck code (output of `jitbf rev.bf --bf`) is:

```
-[+>>+<,+[-[----------[+++++++++>-]]]>[->]<<]<[.<]++++++++++.
```

Same as with the previous answer and the other BF entry this just stores the input and print it in reverse order.

I don't consider this an array since I made no way of random access (yes, I use arrays in (E)BF)  so this is more a stack structure.

Strings do not exist in BF but we do store them in similar manner as in this code.

Comment: [Except for the first `>`, this was already posted.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/22791/16385)

Comment: @hvd I didn't see that. Commented about missing `>` to the other poster and redid my answer to be different (more compatible).

Answer (score 1):

**C++**

```
 int main()
    {
    int num =123456;
    int rev =0;
    while(num)
    {
    rev = (rev *10) + (num%10);
    num = num /10;
    }
    cout << "Reverse :" << rev;
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This program accepts anything from input and outputs it reversed. So it can reverse strings, integers, floating point numbers, leading zero numbers, and other stuff. Please note that I'm not using **strings** but **chars**, so it should be ok.

## PHP, HTML

```php
<?php
    while (false !== ($char = fgetc(STDIN))) {
    ?> <div style="float:right;"> <?= $char ?> </div> <?php
    }
?>
```

I don't know if `float:right` would be considered a string or not, and just in case, here's a longer solution without that.

## PHP, HTML, CSS

```php
<style>
div {
    float:right;
}
</style>

<?php
    while (false !== ($char = fgetc(STDIN))) {
        ?> <div> <?= $char ?> </div> <?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP

No (built in) modulo, no string, no array;

```
function reverse ($n) {
    $r = 0;
    while ($n) {
        $r *= 10;
        $head = (int) ($n / 10);
        $r += $n - 10 * $head;
        $n = $head;
    }

    return $r;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Golfscript

```
-1/
```

Pass an unsigned int as a command line arg

Answer (score 1):

## C#

Using totally unnecessary recursion:

```
int Reverse(int i)
{
    return ReverseRecurse(i, 0);
}

int ReverseRecurse(int i, int r)
{
    if (i==0) return r;
    else
    {
        int d= i/10;
        return ReverseRecurse(d, (10*r)+(i-(d*10)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python

Probably not the best implementation, and I regret the need to import the math module, but here it is!

```
import math

def Reverse(n):
    revNum = 0
    digitsNum = math.floor(math.log10(n))

    for i in range(digitsNum, -1, -1):
        section = n // (10**(digitsNum-i))
        revNum += (section - 10*(section//10)) * 10**i

    return revNum
```

Answer (score 1):

### Java

```
public class Reverser {

    public static long reverse(long x)
    {
        long n = (long) Math.floor(Math.log(x)/Math.log(10));
        long c = 0;
        for (long k=1; k<=n; k++)
        {
            c+= (long) (Math.floor( x * Math.pow(10, -1.0*k)) * Math.pow(10, n-k));
        }

        return (long) (x*Math.pow(10, n)) - (99 * c); 

    }

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        long a= 1230504;
        long b= reverse(a);
        System.out.println(String.format("a=%d, b=%d", a,b));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function recurse(accumulator) {
    var power = accumulator.power;
    accumulator.power *= 10;
    if (accumulator.input >= accumulator.power)
         recurse(accumulator);
    while (accumulator.input >= power) {
        accumulator.input -= power;
        accumulator.result += accumulator.value;
    }
    accumulator.value *= 10;
 }

 function reverse(x) {
    var accumulator = { power: 1, value: 1, input: x, result: 0 };
    recurse(accumulator);
    return accumulator.result;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java

This code has the following limitations:

1. it probably only works on the Eclipse console.
2. it's limited to natural integers.
3. it's artificially limited to a total of 100 figures (accross multiple calculations in sequence), this limit may be increased at the cost of performance, but the bottlenecks are probably the number of cores and the user's patience.
4. it's not thread-safe. Use at your own risk.

It essentially spawns a new Thread for each input byte and sleeps a bit less each time before writing it on the standard output.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter the number you want to reverse.");
    int i = -1;
    int count = 0;
    while (true) {
        try {
            i = System.in.read();
            final int readEntry = i;
            if(readEntry!=13&&readEntry!=10){
                final int wait = count++;
                new Thread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100-wait);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        System.out.print(readEntry-48);
                    }
                }).start();
            }               
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## **C#**

Magic numbers and shifting bits... no division, no modulo, no chars, no strings, no arrays.  Just integers, adding, bit shifts, and multiplication.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UInt32 uin = UInt32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        UInt32 usave = uin;
        UInt64 rl;
        UInt32 q;
        UInt32 uout = 0;
        int digits = 0;
        while (uin > 0){
            rl = (UInt64)3435973837*uin;
            uin = (UInt32)(rl >> 35);
            digits++;
        }
        uin = usave;
        while (uin > 0)
        {
            rl = (UInt64)3435973837 * uin;
            q = (UInt32)(rl >> 35);
            uout += (uin - q * 10)*(UInt32)Math.Pow(10,(digits-1));
            uin = q;
            digits--;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(uout);          
    }
```

This answer actually has some utility because, although it is highly obfuscated, it provides a really fast way to simultaneously implement `div 10` and `modulo 10` in 64-bit code.  See : [How do I implement an efficient 32 bit DivMod in 64 bit code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20287946/327083)

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript**

```
function reverse(num) {
    for(var r = 0; num!=+[]; num = parseInt(num / 10, 10)) {
        r *= 10;
        r += num % 10;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: I would appreciate if the one who voted -1 gave a reason for the same. :)

Answer (score 0):

## C++11

This code builds a function that prints an integer from STDIN in reverse, and then executes that function. Basically it is an example of really bad functional programming with loads of side effects.

```c
#include <cstdio>
#include <functional>

void r(std::function<void()> f) {
    char c = getchar();
    c > 47 && c < 58
    ?   r([=]() {
            putchar(c);
            f();
        })
    :   f();
}

int main() {
    r([]() {
        putchar(10);
    });
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java

```java
int res = 0;
int numb = 25455236;
while(numb > 0){
  int temp = numb;
  int counter = 0;
  while (temp >= 0){
    temp = temp - 10;
    counter++;
  }
  res += 10-(counter*10-numb);
  res *= 10;
  numb = counter-1;
}
System.out.println(res/10);
```

Answer (score 0):

**C**

No mod.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned long n, m=0;
    scanf("%lx", &n);
    while( n ) m = m<<4 | n&0xF, n >>= 4;
    printf("%lx\n", m);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### C

Here is an actual procedure that takes an unsigned as input and returns the reversed value.

```
unsigned long reverse(unsigned long n){
    unsigned long p=1, m=0, q=1;
    while( p<=n ) p *= 10;
    while( p /= 10 ){
        while( p<=n ) n -=p, m+= q;
        q *= 10;
    }
    return m;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Dart

```
r(n, [a=0]) => n>0 ? r(n ~/ 10, a * 10 + n % 10) : a;
```

Use as:

```
main() { print(r(13457)); }  // prints 75431
```

Only works for non-negative integers.