# Output the Iccanobif Sequence

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, fibonacci

Write a program or named function that will output or return the sequence up to the `n`th integer in the Iccanobif sequence, documented on OEIS as [A014258](https://oeis.org/A014258). Note that only the zeroth element in the sequence (`0`) will be printed if `n` is zero.

The sequence is generated by starting like the standard Fibonacci sequence, but after adding the two previous numbers, you flip the result and drop any leading zeros. An interesting fact, to me at least, is that this sequence is not strictly increasing (see the list below). It also seems to be (and probably is) strictly greater than or equal to the Fibonacci sequence.

Your program's input must be an integer.

The first 20 numbers of the sequence are provided here for your viewing pleasure:

```
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 31, 93, 421, 415, 638, 3501, 9314, 51821, 53116, 739401, 715297, 8964541, 8389769
```

Standard loopholes are forbidden.

Shortest program wins.

EDIT: Added a note to clarify that the sequence starts with the zeroth element and should be included if `n` is zero.

#### Example IO possibilities:

```
0    ->    0
1    ->    0 1
6    ->    0 1 1 2 3 5 8
17   ->    [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 31, 93, 421, 415, 638, 3501, 9314, 51821, 53116, 739401, 715297]
```

Now that there are several answers, below are my implementations in Python 2 that I worked hard to hide with markup:

Iterative:

> ```
> #Closest to my initial program. 73 bytes. It should also be noted that this program
>  cannot reach a stack overflow. It runs for n=5000 in less than 10 seconds.
>
> i,a,b=input(),0,1
> print a
> while i:print b;i,a,b=i-1,b,int(str(a+b)[::-1])
> ```

Recursive:

> ```
> #Note that this prints n trailing newlines. 64 bytes.
>  Will hit a stack overflow error for large values of n.
>
> def f(n,i=0,j=1):print i,n and f(n-1,j,int(str(i+j)[::-1]))or'';
> ```

Comment: +1 for thinking of something to do with the Fibonacci sequence that hasn´t been done before

Comment: @steveverrill I decided I wanted to make another challenge, then started with just deciding to see what the sequence would look like, after I imagined it. So I wrote a program. Then I searched OEIS and made the challenge.

Comment: Was it inspired by [this question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2823/shortest-way-to-reverse-a-number/)?

Comment: @JohnE No. I've seen it before, but that challenge is one of the most simple challenges on this site. No, I was just creating a number sequence purely from my imagination that I could use as a challenge.

Comment: I think you should wait a little longer before accepting an answer. Unless one of the answers is clearly unbeatable (e.g., a 1 byte solution), it's advisable to wait at least a week.

Comment: @Dennis I was going to update which answer is accepted if it gets beaten, but I'll un-accept it. You'll probably have to remind me to accept an answer, unless PCG sends reminders.

Comment: @mbomb007 I usually accept an answer after a day or so, and update it when it's beaten. It's not a big deal either way.

Comment: @mbomb007 Why do you require a *named* function?

Comment: Idk. I wrote it in 2015. I'm not going to change it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>17</s> <s>15</s> 14

```
Pu+Gs_`s>2GQU2
```

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Pu%2BGs_%60s%3E2GQU2&input=17&debug=0)

Very basic implementation, starts with `range(2)` and adds a number of elements equal to the input, then <s>slices off the extras</s> pops off the last element.

Thanks @Jakube for pointing out the `>` reversal thingy.

#### Explanation

```
Pu+Gs_`s>2GQU2    : Q = eval(input) (implicit)
P                 : all but the last element
 u         QU2    : reduce Q times starting with [0, 1]
  +G              : add to the previous result
       s>2G       : sum of the last two elements of G
    s_`           : int(reversed(repr(above value)))
```

Answer (score 4):

### Python 2, 58 bytes

```python
a=0;b=1
exec"print a;a,b=b,int(str(a+b)[::-1]);"*-~input()
```

Uses `str` to convert rather than backticks because large enough numbers in Python 2 are written with an L at the end. I tried a recursive function, but it turned out longer (61):

```python
f=lambda n,a=0,b=1:-~n*[0]and[a]+f(n-1,b,int(str(a+b)[::-1]))
```

Answer (score 3):

## K, <s>25</s> 23 bytes

```
{-1_ x{x,.|$+/-2#x}/!2}
```

A simple modification of one of the examples at [No Stinking Loops](http://kx.com/a/k/examples/recur.k).

The phrase `.|$` casts a number to a string, reverses it and then evaluates it.

### Edit:

Sloppy attention to boundary conditions on my part. More correct now:

```
  {-1_ x{x,.|$+/-2#x}/!2}'0 1 6 10
(,0
 0 1
 0 1 1 2 3 5 8
 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 31 93 421 415)
```

### Edit 2:

`(x+1)#` can be replaced with `-1_`, saving 2 characters. The space is necessary because otherwise `_x` would be an identifier, when I want the "drop" operator applied to a variable called `x`.

Comment: According to the OP, the output should start with a zero.

Comment: Correct- Should be fixed now.

Comment: Came here to post an answer only to see you had the exact same one. Nicely done.

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, 79 bytes

```matlab
f=n->(t=[0,1];for i=2:n push!(t,t[i]+t[i-1]|>string|>reverse|>int)end;t[1:n+1])
```

This creates a function that accepts an integer as input and returns an integer array.

Ungolfed + explanation:

```matlab
function f(n)
    # Start with the usual Fibonacci stuff
    t = [0,1]

    # Looooooooooooooop
    for i = 2:n
        # Compute the Iccanobif number by piping results
        iccanobif = t[i] + t[i-1] |> string |> reverse |> int

        # Jam it into t
        push!(t, iccanobif)
    end

    # Return the first n + 1
    t[1:n+1]
end
```

Examples:

```matlab
julia> f(1)
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 0
 1

julia> f(17)
18-element Array{Int64,1}:
      0
      1
      1
      2
      3
      5
      8
     31
     93
    421
    415
    638
   3501
   9314
  51821
  53116
 739401
 715297
```

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>64</s> 49 bytes

```
a!b=a:b!(read$reverse$show$a+b)
q n=0:take n(1!1)
```

Usage example: `q 15` -> `[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,31,93,421,415,638,3501,9314,51821,53116]`

How it works: `!` recursively builds an infinite list of iccanobif numbers starting with it's first argument (the second argument must be the next iccanobif number). `q` takes the first `n` numbers from the iccanobif list starting with `1, 1` and prepends a `0`.

Answer (score 3):

## T-SQL, 149

Very straight forward inline table function that uses a recursive CTE query.  As it is using INTs this will top out at 37.  Adding in CASTs for bigints will allow it to go further to 63

```
create function i(@ int)returns table return with r as(select 0I,1N union all select n,reverse(i+n)+0from r)select 0n union all select top(@)n from r
```

It is used as follows

```
select * from i(0)
n
-----------
0

(1 row(s) affected)

select * from i(1)
n
-----------
0
1

(2 row(s) affected)

select * from i(6)
n
-----------
0
1
1
2
3
5
8

(7 row(s) affected)

select * from i(17)
n
-----------
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
31
93
415
421
638
3501
9314
51821
53116
715297
739401

(18 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 18 bytes

```
U1{_2$+sW%i}ri*;]p
```

**How it works**

```
U1                      e# First two numbers in the series
  {        }ri*         e# Run the loop input numbers times
   _2$+                 e# Get sum of last two numbers in the series
       sW%i             e# Convert to string, inverse and convert back to a number
                ;       e# Remove the last number to get only first n + 1 numbers.
                 ]p     e# Wrap all numbers in an array and print the array
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=U1%7B_2%24%2BsW%25i%7Dri*%3B%5Dp&input=17)

Answer (score 2):

## Java - <s>126</s> 124

I haven't seen Java around this site in awhile...

```
void f(int b){for(int c=0,d=1,g;b-->=0;d=Integer.valueOf(new StringBuilder(c+(c=d)+"").reverse()+""))System.out.println(c);}
```

`f(5)` prints `0 1 1 2 3 5 8 31 93 421 415 638`

Comment: I would also accept `...System.out.println(c);`

Comment: @mbomb007 Thanks! Saved me 2 bytes.

Comment: You could probably shorten it using the [numeric method](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2826/34718) to reverse a number since Java's string manipulation is costly.

Comment: I know it's been more than 1.5 years, but you can save 6 bytes by replacing `Integer.valueOf(` with `new Long(` (and then change the `int` in the for-loop to `long` as well). If you prefer to just work with integers instead, `new Integer(` is still shorter than `Integer.valueOf(`.

Answer (score 2):

## SWI-Prolog, <s>141</s> <s>131</s> 121 bytes

```
a(X,R):-X>1,A is X-1,a(A,B),reverse(B,[K,L|_]),W is K+L,name(W,Z),reverse(Z,Y),name(E,Y),nth0(X,R,E,B);X=1,R=[0,1];R=[0].
```

Running `a(17,X).` outputs:

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 31, 93, 421, 415, 638, 3501, 9314, 51821, 53116, 739401, 715297]
```

Takes about 10 seconds to output the result of `a(10000,X).` on my computer.

Edit: The 121 bytes version above is a one predicate definition = one liner.
The old 131 bytes version is the following (must be runned as `p(17,X)`):

```
a(0,[0]).
a(1,[1,0]).
a(X,[E|B]):-A is X-1,a(A,B),B=[K,L|_],W is K+L,name(W,Z),reverse(Z,Y),name(E,Y).
p(X,Y):-a(X,Z),reverse(Z,Y).
```

Answer (score 2):

### [><> (Fish)](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish) <s>592</s> 254 Bytes

Not super golfed (42/43 blanks that do nothing and a total of 30 redirection tokens) , but was an interesting exercise getting it working in the first place.

```
10!/{:}0=?v/{1-}}:{+:0}!/a,:1%-:0=?!v~{:1!/$:@0=?!v$~}}:&{{&*\
/-$/    ;n/\oo", "n:    \       }+1{/     \$-1$*a /|.!20}}01@/
* :{:}(?v:{!":}-1!/$:@0=?!v$~{:}1!/$:@0=?!v$~}}}:&{{{&*:1%-*&{{&+}}{1+}02.
b .1 +bb   \      \$-1$*a /       \$-1$,a /
\*9{~~~{/
```

You can test it [here](http://fishlanguage.com/playground/6rsxwkJHFgobme6gf), providing the desired length in the initial stack.

EDIT: More than halved byte count

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <strike>114</strike>, 109 bytes

```
function f($n){if($n==0)return 0;$f=[0,1];for($i=2;$i<=$n;++$i){$f[$i]=strrev($f[$i-1]+$f[$i-2]);}return $f;}
```

Nothing fancy, just an average fibonacci algorithm with the string reverse magic.

Ungolfed:

```
function f($n)
{
    if($n == 0) return 0;
    $f = [0, 1];
    for ($i=2; $i<=$n; ++$i){
        $f[$i] = strrev($f[$i-1] + $f[$i-2]);
    }
    return $f;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 10 bytes

```
↑¡ȯ↔Σ↑_2ŀ2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbxEMLT6x/1Dbl3GIgO97oaIPR////DS0A)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES2015), <s>81</s> 73 bytes

```
(a,b=0,c=1)=>{for(;a-->-1;c=[...(b+(b=+c)+"")].reverse().join``)alert(b)}
```

Running this function (named `f`) with `6`:

```
f(6);// alerts: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Excel VBA, 279 bytes

```
n = InputBox("n")
For i = 0 To n
If i < 2 Then
Cells(i + 1, 1) = i
ElseIf i > 6 Then
x = Cells(i, 1) + Cells(i - 1, 1)
l = Len(x)
v = CStr(x)
For j = 1 To l
r = r + Right(v, 1)
v = Left(v, l - j)
Next j
Cells(i + 1, 1) = r
r = ""
Else
Cells(i + 1, 1) = Cells(i, 1) + Cells(i - 1, 1)
End If
Next i
```

Running the macro will prompt the user to enter a value for n.

The results will then be printed row by row in column A:

[image: Output]

Comment: Can you remove spaces in your code to make it shorter?

Comment: @mbomb007 when writing in Excel VBA the spaces are automatically entered, so I just leave them in.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 13 bytes

I'm pretty sure all the features used in this program were present in Pip before this question was asked.

```
LaSio:+RVi+oi
```

Takes input as command-line argument. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#@@@TGJyZb6UdFJapnZ/5//9/SwA)

#### Explanation

```
               a is 1st cmdline arg; i is 0; o is 1 (implicit)
La             Loop (a) times:
       RVi+o   Reverse of i+o
      +        Unary + treats its operand as a number, thus removing leading 0's
    o:         Assign the result to o...
  Si           ... before swapping i and o
            i  After the loop, output i
```

The two variables' values evolve like so:

```
Iter   o   i (output)
   0   1   0
   1   0   1
   2   1   1
   3   1   2
   4   2   3
   5   3   5
   6   5   8
   7   8  31
   8  31  93
   9  93 421
  10 421 415
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
+ṚḌɗÐ¡1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARkA5v9qZWxsef//K@G5muG4jMmXw5DCoTH//zEw)

Reads `n` from STDIN

### How it works

```
+ṚḌɗÐ¡1 - Main link. No arguments
        - By default, set the left argument to 0
      1 - Set the right argument to 0
    Ð¡  - Read n from STDIN and do the following n times:
          Start with x = 0, y = 1, then update according to
          x, y = y, f(x,y), collecting each intermediate step
   ɗ    - Define f(x, y):
+       -   x + y
 Ṛ      -   Reversed digits
  Ḍ     -   Back to integer
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `W`, <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
01?(~+Ṙ)_
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJXIiwiIiwiMDE/KH4r4bmYKV8iLCIiLCIxNyJd)

-1 thanks to Steffan

Similar to the [CJam](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52092/107299) answer.

```
01?(~+Ṙ)_ # 'W' flag prints the entire stack
01        # Push 0, then 1
  ?(   )  # Loop input number of times
    ~+    # Add the previous 2 numbers without popping
      Ṙ   # Reverse the result (given a number, the output will be a number)
        _ # Pop the last result
```

Comment: You can remove the space because of how leading zeros are parsed.

Comment: You can do this to sve another byte: `01?(~+Ṙ…`

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 87 bytes

```r
function(n)while(n+1){n=n-1;show(+F);F=T+(T=F);F=F%/%10^(z=0:log10(F))%%10%*%10^rev(z)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc05CoAwEEDR0wRmDGKmVabNCawFDS4BmYArKJ49Lo3d5zV/it65WkLjO47dKm7xQUBwH/zYgmjCU1hSKuYh7KAtFpZLDSV/ZVWmyFRwsMnH0JMBi6geUsnrU7vBgde/ACKMNw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 18 bytes (non-competing)

```
Z1{:2d+vFs@KjkvF;_
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pushy#@x9lWG1llKJd5lbs4J2VXeZmHf///38jAwMA)**

It's not the most elegant of programs, but it works.

```
Z1     \ Push 0 and 1 to begin the sequence
{:     \ Input times do:
 2d+   \   Add the last two terms
 vF    \   Send to second stack
 s     \   Split into digits
 @Kjk  \   Reverse and join into one number
 vF;    \   Send back to first stack
_      \ At the end of the program, print the whole stack.
```

Comment: @mbomb007 yep, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
0+ṚV$¥Ð¡1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99A@@HOWWEqh5YennBooeH///8NzQE)

Answer (score 0):

## R, 134 bytes

```
i=function(n){s=c(0,1);for(i in 3:n){s[i]=as.numeric(paste0(rev(strsplit(as.character(s[i-2]+s[i-1]),'')[[1]]),collapse=''))};cat(s)}
```

Example:

```
> i(10)
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 31 93 421
```

Would love to see if somebody had a better R alternative than to take your number, make it a string, reverse it and turn it back into a number again.

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, 70 bytes

```
{r={"$it".reverse() as int};f={n->n<3?1:r(f(n-1))+r(f(n-2))};r(f(it))}
```

---

```
{
    r={"$it".reverse() as int};       // Reverse digits, costly using string.
    f={n->n<3?1:r(f(n-1))+r(f(n-2))}; // Recursive Iccanobbif implementation.
    r(f(it))                          // Reverse final output.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Outputs the `n`th element, 0-indexed.

```
@Zä+ Ìsw}g
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QFrkKyDMc3d9Zw&input=MTc)